# How to display a calculation on data values in R legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here's a fiddle for a [simplified version of a plot](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=NbKDhPQF&version=15) I am trying to generate.

On line 44  the plot points are sized according to 1/Error:

```
main_aes = aes(x = Date, y = Popular_Support, size=1/Error)
```

But instead of displaying `1/Error` values in the legend, I want it to display `Sample Size` which is `1/Error^2`, which the legend title being `Sample Size`.

I only want this displayed in the legend, but I still want the original values to weight the point sizes.

How can I do this? How can I perform a calculation on the legend text that is displayed and change the legend title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
plot + scale_size_continuous(breaks=seq(40,70,10), labels=seq(40,70,10)^2,
                             name="Sample Size")
```

Also, `plot` is an R function, so it's probably better to use a different name for your plot objects.